# Extracting a specified string in a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python that contains strings like`['abc','defg',xyz','lmnopqrst']`. I need to iterate through the list and extract elements in the **2nd** and **3rd** position and create another list with just those letters
ex : O/P should be a list which has `['bc','ef','yz','mn']`

Comment: Please post some code, and formally state what exactly the problem is with it.

Comment: by just those alphabets i mean alphabets in the 2nd and 3rd position

Comment: When you say alphabets, I think you mean "letters"

Comment: yes..apologies..i mean letters

Comment: as a follow up what if the list was as follows :
['abc' , '1234','defg','xyz','6898','lmnopq'] and I wanted only the following list as my O/P :
['bc','ef','yz','mn']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
new_list = [ s[1:3] for s in your_list ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) notation:

```
output_list = [s[1:3] for s in input_list]
```